# Can someone give example what could go wrong if constructor is used in upgradable contracts?

Tags: contract-upgrading

I have been reading that logic contracts should use initialize method rather than a constructor since it's not a part of deployed bytecode. What I don't understand is what could go wrong if I use it.

In my undertanding, say proxy is:

```
contract Proxy {
    uint256 public a;
}

contract Logic {
    uint256 public _a;

    constructor(uint256 a) {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

What I do in Logic contract is initialize `_a` which is in Logic contract. Wouldn't the Proxy update `a` to `_a`? Obviously I am missing something.

Can someone give an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are only called during the contract deployment, proxies can't access that information as it's stored on the original contract not on the proxy, meaning, **proxies are completely oblivious to the existence of constructors**.

So, all the initialization will be lost since it was run in the context of the Logic contract and not the Proxy contract. More info about this [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies#the-constructor-caveat).

Comment: Why proxies needs to access the logic contrac't constructor. Once the constructor is run in the logic contract, the state variable of the logic contract will be updated and as a result, the corresponding state variable in the proxy contract will also get updated.

Comment: Proxies dont need access to constructors for this reason, the context in used in a proxy patter is the proxy one, if you make a direct call to the logic contract and change anything the proxy data will never be updated

Answer (score 0):

This was a question which was bothering me for a long time too and I also couldn't find a proper explanation. Let me summarise how I understood it:

1. This is the difference between a Smart Contract and EOA account [image]

2.Taking a closer look, it is good to see that each smart contract has code and storage.

3. Storage is the place where we store the changes from saved to the smart contract.
4. Code is the place where the smart contract code is stored as well as all the information included in the **constructor**
5. Now see that those are 2 different places.
6. This is why we can't use constructor. Because when we use the constructor we will save everything passed inside, to the code location and not to the storage.
7. Remember Proxies read from Storage location not from code location.
8. That is why we need to use initialisation, because whatever we save into the initialisation will be stored to the storage. The name initialisation is not fixed like storage, you can name it whatever you want. Important is that it is called only once and called from the person who deploys the contract, because if it is called from someone else and it changes some roles like admin, it will make the first caller the admin.
9. Remember proxies read from Storage not from code.

I hope you that it is more clear now, but in order to understand it it important to understand the difference between those 2 storage and code. I think this is missing in most of the explanations and lead to so many confusions.